# How can i quit definetively a screen when navigating to another one in react native Tab navigation?

Tags: react-native, tabs, navigation, screen, exit

I tried to use this: **this.props.navigation.navigatie('Screen')** it works but it keep the old screen active in the background. I am using a barcode scanner and i don't want it to drain energy by running in the backgroun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `reset` method from stack actions :

[documentation here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/2.x/stack-actions/#reset)

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' })],
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```